# How not to delete a row if it has children

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a One to Many relation : One row in modelParent with Many row in modelChild

In a PanelList with the all modelParent rows, I want to hide the delete Icone on the row if the row has children link to this row.

What test should I do ?

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Right way**

Don't hide the delete button, but show confirmation dialog that would tell user how many related records would be deleted with the selected record. You can find code samples in [Project Tracker](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/), [People Skills](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/people-skills/) and lots of [other templates](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/).

**Easy to implement way** (worse performance)

1. Configure [prefetch](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#prefetch) for your `ParentModel`'s datasource to include records from `ChildModel`
2. Bind delete button's `visibe` property to this:

```javascript
@datasource.item.<NameOfYourRelationField>.length === 0
```

**Harder to implement way** (better performance)

You can create calculated model with special flag that you can use on UI to show/hide the delete button. This approach will also require lots of extra scripting for CRUD operations.